# Java io handle is invalid exception

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I have a function that reads from the console using readPassword(). This function is called several times in one program iteration. However, I keep getting a java io exception once it gets to the readPassword() line. I noticed when i removed the close() statement from the finally-clause this error disappears. Why does this happen and when should I properly close the reader?

```
public void Func()
{
        Console console = System.console();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        if (console == null)
            System.out.println("Error!");

        try 
        {
           char[] pwd = console.readPassword();
           String password = new String(pwd);
           System.out.println("PW: " + password);

           String input = reader.readLine();
           System.out.println("UserNm: " + input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Exception messages are very useful when debugging. As in: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I do regularly print out the stacktrace in my actual code. This is just a stub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any reader here, just use the `Console` instance.

```
public String Func() {
        Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("No console available");

        try {
           String username = console.readLine("Username: ");
           String pwd = new String(console.readPassword("Password: "));
           return pwd;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
}
```

Edited with your question edit. Just use the Console class, it can read/write, you don't need any reader/writer.

Answer (score 4):

There's only one console, and there's only one `System.in`. If you close it, then you can't read from it anymore! You don't need to close that `BufferedReader`, nor should you. That whole `finally` block can and should just go away.

On closer reading, I don't even see why you're *creating* the `BufferedReader` in the first place -- it seems to have no function. Just delete all the code that deals with it!

Comment: Even if I access System.console() again each time the function is called? This is probably bad practice on my part. If I don't close it can I count on garbage collection to handle it for me?

Comment: Garbage collection won't close it, because *it should not be closed*, is my point. You can call System.console() as many times as you like without worry.

Comment: Sorry about that. I re-edited my original post. I was using the BufferedReader to read in a username and the Console to read in password since Console has access to the handy readPassword() func.

Answer (score 1):

You should not close your `Console`. Keep it open until your program does no longer need to read from it.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like java.util.Scanner instead and as other people say don't worry about ever trying to close system.in.

So much cleaner:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String password  = in.nextLine(); 
String username  = in.nextLine();
```

No tidy up/exception handling required.

Comment: @alex's answer is nicer because of the readPassword bit. Not storing it as a string and suppressing output of the text